# Etymology of reflection?

Tags: reflection, metaprogramming

I've never found a clear explanation for the *etymology* of reflection in the context of computer languages, so I want to clarify this here.

"Reflection" originates from Latin and has the following [definitions](http://latin-dictionary.net/definition/33126/reflecto-reflectere-reflexi-reflexus):

> - bend back
> - turn back
> - turn round

So the idea behind it is a language that is able to bend back on itself, to be able to look and manipulate its own code.

Or is there something else?

[Reflection in logic, functional and object-oriented programming:
a Short Comparative Study Francois-Nicola Demers and Jacques Malenfant (PDF)](http://www-master.ufr-info-p6.jussieu.fr/2006/Ajouts/Master_esj_2006_2007/IMG/pdf/malenfant-ijcai95.pdf) seems to agree:

> Reflection is the process of reasoning about and/or acting upon oneself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term reflection was (according to the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming))) coined by Brian Cantwell Smith in his dissertation [Procedural reflection in programming languages](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/15961).

The prologue starts

> It is a striking fact about human cognition that we can think not only about the world around us, but also about our ideas, our actions, our feelings. our past experience. This ability to *reflect* lies behind much of the subtlety and flexibility with which we deal with the world; it is an essential part of mastering new skills, of reacting to unexpected circumstances, ...
>
> (---)
>
> This last aspect -- the self-referential aspect of reflective thought -- has sparked particular interest for cognitive theorists...
>
> (---)
>
> In artifial intelligence, the focus on computational forms of self-referential reflective reasoning has become particularly central.

And then it summarises the **reflection hypothesis** as

> In as much as a computational process can be constructed to reason about an external world in virtue of comprising an ingredient process (interpreter) formally manipulating representations of that world, so too a computational process could be made to reason about itself in virtue of comprising an ingredient process (interpreter) formally manipulating representations of its own operations and structures.

The use of *reflection* is tied to *self-representation* and *self-reference* which to me suggests that of the alternatives in the question, the closest is *bend back* as also given in the [etymonline entry on reflection](https://www.etymonline.com/word/reflection):

> Of the mind, from 1670s. Meaning "remark made after turning back one's thought on some subject" is from 1640s. Spelling with -ct- recorded from late 14c., established 18c., by influence of the verb.